# Is it okay to add a DomainObject as a property of a CommandObject?

Tags: grails

I was using a grails CommandObject to store all the information for a search page.  Something Like

```
class SomeSearchCommand {
     User user
     ...
     Integer max=100
     Integer offset=0
}
```

And then in the controller

```
class SomeThingController {
    def search(SomeSearchCommand c) {
        // build a query based SomeSearchCommand
        Something.where {
            if (c.user) user==c.user
            ...
        }.list(max: c.max, offset: c.offset)
    } 
}
```

This appears to work well, and when you call the action with

```
/someThing/search?user=3&offset=100
```

It finds all the "SomeThing" objects that belong to user 3.

But while playing around with the code I found out that if you change the url to

```
/someThing/search?user.id=3&user.name=ichangedyourname&offset=100
```

Then the User object inside of the domain object would be loaded with id=3 from the database, and the user.name property would be changed.  The User object is now marked as dirty and has been added to the session.  If you happen to execute some code that calls a flush (or have flushMode set to Auto), then the change to the user object is persisted.

I found a workaround by adding a @BindUsing around the user object.  This seems to disable the deep binding on the user object and only allows binding by the parameter of `user` and not `user.id`

```
class SomeSearchCommand {
     @BindUsing({obj, source ->
          if (source['user'] instanceOf User) return source['user']
          if (source['user'] instanceOf serializable) return User.get(source['user'])
     })
     User user
     ...
     Integer max=100
     Integer offset=0
}
```

Another workaround is to just not use the User Domain Object in the CommandObject.

```
class SomeSearchCommand {
     String userId
     User getUser() {
         return User.get(userId)
     }
     ...
     Integer max=100
     Integer offset=0
}
```

This means the URL request has to change to `/some/search?userId=3&offset=100`

But `user` is still a property on the command object that returns the typed object.

I first noticed this using grails 2.3.11 (where flushMode is set to auto), so that the inner domain object was always being written to the database.
In grails version after 2.4 the flush mode is set to Manual, so the modified domain object only gets persisted of the session is flushed.

I don't see any examples in the grails docs about putting a domainObject inside a commandObject.  It always seems to be basic types.

Comment: I would not use critical domain objects like `User` in a `CommandObject` since you never know what kind of operations they make upon initialization and you encounter the problem you are seeing. Instead you should treat `CommandObjects` as `ViewModels` and create `inner Class` in the `CommandObject` that represents the `User` returned from the `request`, then later on when you process the `CommandObject` you bind its data to the actual `DomainClass User`

Comment: thanks for the response @TuomasValtonen.  I think you touched on the point I was trying to make when you said "since you never know what kind of opertions they make upon initialization.."   I was caught by surprise when those operations included modifying the object inside the CommandObject.

Comment: well, while that is true. What i was trying to say is that Domain Objects may have a lot of other actions they perform, like hooks when they are fetched from database, eager fetching of complex and expensive structures, active record quirks etc. Better to stick with a structure that you have control over since you are only mapping http-data to an object